# Xfce entered zoom mode. How do I exit?

Tags: linux-mint, x11, xfce

I pressed something around my mouse pad (keys in the altgr region+mousepad - quite possibly multitouch) and suddenly the whole X11 display zoomed around 10%. That means I can see 90% of the 1920x1080 screen in a somewhat blurry version. When I move the cursor, the 90% follows the cursor, so by panning around I can see everything on the screen. Since it applies to everything my guess is that it is caused by xfwm or Xorg.

If I suspend the machine, it seems to go away in the lock screen, but when the lock screen is unlocked, the blurriness and zoom re-appears. Taking a screenshot grabs what is displayed on my screen (i.e. the 90% but scaled to 1920x1080).

I can see the usefulness of this in certain situations, but I would really like to exit it (other than rebooting).

I use xfce on Linux Mint.

Comment: You could even disable the zoom feature, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/479465/21005).

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I somehow ended up with an extremely large InitialZoom=6.327399706912535e+119  in my .config/kwinrc file, changing that to 1 solved my 'stuck in zoom' problem

Answer (score 154, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + *scrollwheel*.

So in my case, I had pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *two fingers* on the mouse pad.

(If you are in a Linux VM using a Mac, then the combination is  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + *scroll wheel*)

Comment: PHEW!  That's a relief.

Comment: It works, but in my case, only after logging in. on the logging screen works Only the Alt+Windows+8keyboard shortcut (@Lin's answer).

Comment: If you've bound window dragging to Super+drag (in Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility), zoom is controlled by Super+scroll rather than Alt+scroll.

Comment: Is it possible to have high definition while zooming?

Answer (score 16):

**To Turn on or Turn off Zoom** within login screen, 
you may use: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: Not every keyboard that is being used with Linux has a 'Windows' key ;-)

Comment: @Time4Tea That's all very nice and elite and superior for you to say, but alt+super+8 does indeed toggle a global screen magnifier in ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: This saved me thanks -- zoom is a really poorly implemented feature in Ubuntu 18.04, acessibility my a$$. :'D

Comment: Oh, is that some key binding specific to Xfce version of Linux Mint? What does it run?

Comment: I'm using only the mousepad on my laptop, and the "accepted answer" of Alt+scrollwheel didn't work for me. This suggestion worked, on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This works in PopOS as well, but take not they it's `8` not `F8`. I initially misread that.

Answer (score 3):

This zoom mode is traditionally bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Keypad +</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Keypad -</kbd> to zoom out. These keys are not available if the `DontZoom` option is set in the `ServerFlags` section of [`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml).

This feature is operated by the server, I don't know how to set it from a client. The [`xrandr`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.xhtml) command may influence it with its `--scale` option, or some other option may be able to reset the zoom setting; I'm unfamiliar with the interactions between the old-time server zoom and the modern RandR support.

Comment: I thought it might be that, but ctrl-alt-+ and - do nothing and also was clearly not the keys I pressed. It would also require several mode lines (or equivalent), and there is only one resolution. But I found the solution: Alt+scrollwheel (which on my mouse pad is two fingers). http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2208553

Comment: Also the Xorg-zoom mode would not explain why the zoom is disabled at the screen lock.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. As mentioned above alt + scroll button or alt + two-finger tap has worked for most but didn't work for me.
I had to go to System Settings > Desktop Effects - workspace behavior. In there the Accessibility section has a Zoom option. I had to disable that option

Edit: I am using KDE and not Xfce but was facing the exact same problem

Comment: That is because you use KDE, not Xfce, right?

Comment: As for disabling the feature in Xfce, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/479465/21005).

Comment: @jarno, Yes you are correct : )

Answer (score 1):

Try using [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr).
My problem (with Linux Mint and losing the margins to overscan on a TV) was corrected that way.